# Panda's or Postgres is adding trailing zeroes and a 1 onto some numeric fields when inserting into DB

Tags: python, pandas, postgresql

Sorry for the long title.

But i have a csv file I'm reading into a Panda's Dataframe.

This value is say 567.188, once its in my df its being read as 567.188e9 then when I insert into the a Postgres SQL V13 using the `df.to_sql()` in my postgres db I now see `567.1880000001`

Why is there a 1 at the end that is breaking all my joins.

Comment: Excuse my rushed question. Ill clean it up in a bit. But the main idea is there.

Comment: What data type is that column? If it's `float` or `double precision` this [is expected](https://floating-point-gui.de/)

Comment: See also [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/5320906).

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name its a numeric on the DB and the csv is defining the col_type as decimal.

Comment: @snakecharmerb I'm not done reading but I see where there issue could be, thanks for this.

Comment: 1) CSV files are text so all values are strings. 2) Postgres is probably not the culprit: `select '567.188'::numeric;` or `select '567.188'::float`; both yield `567.188` with `show extra_float_digits ;` set to the default of 1. 3) Why use a dataframe? Instead use `psycopg2` [Copy](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#using-copy-to-and-copy-from) methods directly.